# javascript no action on dropdown click

Tags: javascript

When I click twice on my dropdown I have this error message

**error :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data on the second click**

Do you know where is the problem?

Thank you.

HTML code

```
      $content .= '<div id="myAjax">';
        $content .= HTML::selectMenu('move_to_category_id[]', $category_tree, $current_category_id, 'id="move_to_category_id"');
        $content .= '</div>';

$categories_ajax = CLICSHOPPING::link('ajax/products_categories.php');
```

the javacript (updated works fine now)

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    console.log("DOM entièrement chargé et analysé");
 document.querySelector('#myAjax')
 .addEventListener('click',function(e){
   var selectedOptionVal = document.querySelector('#move_to_category_id').value
   ,options_html="";
  fetch("{$categories_ajax}?"+selectedOptionVal)
    .then(function(response) {
       return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(jsonResponse) {
   // équivalent à success d'ajax 
   console.log("data is :",jsonResponse);
   for(var index in jsonResponse){
    let category_id = jsonResponse[index].id;
    let category_name = jsonResponse[index].text;
    let selectedString = category_id == selectedOptionVal ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    options_html += '<option value="' + category_id + '"' + selectedString + '>' + category_name + '</option>';
   }
   $('#move_to_category_id').html(options_html);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
     //équivalent à error d'ajax 
   alert("error :"+err);
  });
 });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you try to find the problem?

Comment: First Isuppose the problem comme there : {$categories_ajax}+selectedOptionVal

Comment: I updated "{$categories_ajax}"  but I have this message now : error :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data on  the second click

Comment: Those are important details to include in the body of your question.

Comment: updated title and message

Comment: You're calling `response.json()` but it's possible that the response was not in JSON format.  Perhaps you should do some investigating and examine what the actual response was?  (possibly an HTML formatted or plain-text formatted error message)  Or perhaps `"{$categories_ajax}"+selectedOptionVal` is not the correct way to form the URL you are after.  (missing a `/` or something?).  I'm just guessing, whereas you can investigate directly.  Please do so.

Comment: the first click I have : http://......ajax/products_categories.php and the second click I have : http:// ...........ajax/products_categories.php0. It's in relation with that {$categories_ajax}"+selectedOptionVal

Comment: Let's pump the brakes a little.  This will go better if you've done all the investigation you can and come to Stack Overflow with a detailed breakdown of a problem you cannot further make sense of.  As is, this question is likely to be closed with "needs debugging details".   Anyway, this is a facepalm because  `products_categories.php0` is clearly not the right way to append `0` onto the base url, right?  Important to note that this detail was not in the text of your question.  (It should have been.)

Comment: find the solution "{$categories_ajax}?"+selectedOptionVal - add ?